# select top item with ion-infinite-scroll in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, scroll

I have

```html
<ion-content bg-dark class="has-subheader has-footer has-tabs">
   <div class="list active">
    <div class="item item-divider" ng-repeat="item in controller.list" align="center" >
     <h2  class="default" ng-click="controller.load(item.a,item.b)" ng-class="{'selected':item.b==controller.b}" align="center">{{item.b}}</h2>
    </div>    
   </div>
        <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!controller.noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="controller.load()" distance="5%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
```

and my .css file is

```css
.selected{
    color:black !important;
}

.default{
    color:#7b7a7a;
}
```

i need to select the third item from the top when i scroll and make that item as active and also i need to know how to get that item in controller

i tried using

$ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top;

but its not working!!!

[image]

the above image shows what i needed when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to select it when the list loads, saving it in your scope variable `listenCtrl.b`.

And maybe you are not calling your scope correctly in that case, I'm guessing you are using `controllerAs` and accessing the scope with `controller.`, but in the ng-class you access to `listenCtrl` instead. Probably you have to use `controller` as well.

Comment: Sorry,that was a typing mistake,its not the problem!

Comment: I need the item at that position,not the position value

Comment: Why prevents you from just selecting it with the array and the position? like controller.b = controller.list[2]. I think it's not clear when you want to select it, "when you scroll"? As soon as you are scrolling? when the user makes a long touch on the screen?

Comment: When i scroll ,i need selection same as ios dropdown ,added some more details to my question